# Do cloned tomatillos pollinate each other?

Tags: vegetables, cuttings, pollination, tomatillos

For tomatillos that require a pollinator, if I have only one tomatillo plant, but I root some cuttings from it, will the plants pollinate the other clones (and/or the parent)? They're all from the same plant, originally, and should be clones. So, I'm guessing they wouldn't pollinate each other well. Is this true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, basically, cuttings are clones, so treat them as one plant when dealing with pollination. If the original plant couldn't self-pollinate, neither will the clones.

Comment: Just for clarity, I meant, Will the cuttings pollinate the parent, each other and vice versa? I edited the question. Is that what you understood when you answered?

Comment: @Shule yeah, they're genetically the same plant. I understood the original question.